# Display tag links on archive page?

Tags: php, tags, archives, custom-post-type-archives

How do I dynamically show a list of all available tags with links to their own archive pages on the top of my customized `archive.php` page?

Basically I have: `site.com/cameras` and on the top I would like a list of tags
`digital`, `SLR`, `Instant`, `all`.

If a user clicks digital (for example) they would go to `site.com/cameras/tags/digital` (or whatever URL for that tag is).

Is this possible through editing the template or through an extension?

Comment: Please show us any code that you tried.

Comment: We definitely need some code to be able to help you with this. Is `camera` a custom post type and do you have a specific taxonomy associated with that post type?